# What is the average value of a logistic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the logistic function is given by

$$E= \frac{H}{1+e^{-c}e^{-aN}}$$

How can I know its average value with respect to N, with an interval for all positive numbers?
Thank you

Comment: Average with respect to which variable, on what interval?

Comment: With respect to N, with an interval for all positive numbers

Comment: Have you sketched the function for, say, $0 \leq N \leq 10$?

Comment: It would be 0 ≤ N ≤ x

Comment: I don't think there is a closed-form formula for the finite sum. This is a modified geometric sequence. As the function is analytically integrable on $N$, you can resort to the Euler-Maclaurin fomula for an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the average from $0$ (or $1$) to infinity, it suffices to notice that $E$ asymptotically tends to $H$ (fairly quickly), which is the average.